# Using list as operand

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, global, operand

I am running into a problem when passing a list to a function. It appears to have a global effect on the list variable, but I did not declare it as global in my function. Can anyone tell me what's happening and how to work around it?

```
def a_Minus_b(a,b):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        print("a= ", a)
        if b[i] in a:
            a.remove(b[i])
    return a

x = [1,2,3,4]
a_Minus_b(x,x)
a=  [1, 2, 3, 4]
a=  [2, 3, 4]
a=  [2, 4]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#115>", line 1, in <module>
    a_Minus_b(x,x)
  File "<pyshell#112>", line 4, in a_Minus_b
    if b[i] in a:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns, it will be worth the time.

Comment: Do not loop by index. `for i in range(len(iterable)): iterable[i]` is an antipattern in python. Just do `for value in iterable`

Comment: Although I highly recommend the complete video, the part that deals with functions starts at 15:50

Comment: Containers, like `list`s, are effectively passed by reference in Python, so your function changes the one it's passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python functions can mutate their arguments, if the argument itself is mutable and python lists are.

If you want to have you function without side effects, copy the data first.

```
def a_minus_b(a, b):
    a = list(a) # makes a copy and assigns the copy to a new *local* variable
    for val in b:
        print("a = ", a)
        if val in a:
            a.remove(val)
    return a
```

instead of

```
a = list(a)
```

you can use any of:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy


a = a[:]         # copies only the references in the list
a = a.copy()     # copies only the references in the list
a = copy(a)      # copies only the references in the list
a = deepcopy(a)  # creates copies also of the items in the list
```

Also, what you are doing is builtin in python, it is the `filter` function.
It takes an iterable and a function and returns only the elements of the iterable where the function evaluates to `True`.

```
print(list(filter(a, lambda elem: elem in b))
```

`filter` returns an iterator, to convert it into a list, call `list` on it.